# Keep Angular - xeditable in edit mode

Tags: angularjs

I am using an angular component called [Angular - xeditable](https://vitalets.github.io/angular-xeditable/#editable-row) to basically perform all CRUD within a table . The problem is that if I create a new row to a new record , leaving the fields blank and click " Save" it disables the edit mode , I need you as the user does not inform all the record fields continue mode edition.

Comment: Have you tried to add validation to your fields https://vitalets.github.io/angular-xeditable/#validate-local ? Can you please submit code example?

Comment: Thanks @KostyaShkryob. That link worked like a charm. Can you put in the answer so i can mark as the correct answer?